# Sum with Bernoulli polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, bernoulli-polynomials

I'm trying to prove the following identity:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac {\binom n k B_k(x)} {(n-k+1)} = x^n$$

I transformed this identity as follow:
$$\dfrac{1}{(n+1)}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom {n+1} k B_k(x) = x^n$$

Also I tried to do the following:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac {C_n^k B_k(x)}{(n-k+1)} = n!\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac {B_k(x)}{k!} \dfrac {1}{(n+1-k)!}$$
I add and subtract the (n+1)th summand:
$$n!\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \dfrac {B_k(x)}{k!} \dfrac {1}{(n+1-k)!}-\dfrac{B_{n+1}(x)}{n+1}$$
Denote: $$ a_k= \dfrac {B_k(x)}{k!}, b_{n+1-k}=1$$ Hence:
$$A(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac {B_k(x)}{k!}t^k=\dfrac {te^{xt}}{e^t-1}$$
$$B(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac {t^k}{k!}=e^t$$
$$n!A(t)B(t)=n!\dfrac {e^{t(x+1)}t}{e^t-1}$$
I want to prove it: $$\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac {\binom n k B_k(x)} {(n-k+1)} = x^n$$

So, I find the exponential generating function for the right side of the equality:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac {(x^nt)^k}{k!}=e^{x^nt}$$
So I reformulated this task as follow.
Can we prove that: 
$$n!\dfrac {e^{t(x+1)}t}{e^t-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac {B_k(x)}{k}t^k +e^{x^nt}$$ Unfortunately, I can't find $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac {B_k(x)}{k}t^k$$

Hope you can help me to prove this identity. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Formatting tip: `\infty` is displayed as $\infty$.

Comment: Vizag, Thanks you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last sum presented won't converge.  Here is a simpler approach:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{B_k(x)}{n-k+1} = 
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}B_k(x) \int_0^1 u^{n-k} du = \int_0^1 B_n(x+u) du$$
where in the last step an interchange of $\sum$ and $\int$ has been performed, and the 'translation identity' has been used (see the wiki page).  Shift the integral and and you'll get
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{B_k(x)}{n-k+1}= \int_{x}^{x+1}B_n(u) \,du = x^n$$
where another ID from the wiki page has been used (which can be taken as a definition).  If this is for a homework problem, then you'd probably want to prove the identities in this proof.

ADDENDUM:
Here's a proof of the 'translation theorem' using generating functions. (It's assumed the reader is familiar with the generating function for the Bernoulli polynomials.)
$$\quad (T) \quad \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\, u^{n-k} \,B_k(x) = B_n(x+u) $$
It's easy to see that
$$\quad (*) \quad \frac{t\,e^{t\,x}}{e^t-1} e^{t\,u} = \frac{t\,e^{t\,(x+u)}}{e^t-1}.$$
On the left-hand side (LHS), make a Cauchy product:
$$ LHS(*)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}B_k(x)\cdot \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{t^m}{m!}u^m = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\, u^{n-k} \,B_k(x).$$
On the RHS, use the generating function again.  Formula (T) follows by equating coefficients of $t.$

Comment: I can't find 'translation identity'. Can you send a link about this and a link about the next definition?

Comment: @Katy. See addendum.

Comment: Cool, Thank you very much:)

Comment: Where I can see proof of $ \int_{x}^{x+1}B_n(u) \,du = x^n$?

Comment: Okay, I guess I should ask this question separately)

Comment: Hint: differentiate the given identity to get $B_n(x+1) - B_n(x) = n \ x^{n-1}.$  Use generating functions to prove identity.  You're finished, up to a constant.

Comment: I found my mistake. Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $e^{x t}$ as an expansion in the following way.
\begin{align}
e^{x t} &= \frac{e^t -1}{t} \, \frac{t e^{x t}}{e^t -1} \\
&= \frac{1}{t} \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n!} \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_{k}(x) \, t^k}{k!} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_{k}(x) \, t^{n+k}}{k! \, (n+1)!} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} t^n \, \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{B_{k}(x)}{k! \, (n-k+1)!} \\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n t^n}{n!} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n!} \, \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n! \, B_{k}(x)}{k! \, (n-k+1)!}. 
\end{align}
Equating coefficients leads to
$$(n+1) \, x^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n+1}{k} \, B_{k}(x)$$
or 
$$ x^n = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{k} \, \frac{B_{k}(x)}{n-k+1}.$$

Comment: Why did you replace $t^k$ in the numerator by $(n-k+1)!$ in the denominator? Why we can do this?